# Adding elements to a HashSet while Iterating

Tags: java, multithreading, iterator, hashset

So my program is a version of paint.

It creates a canvas and allows me to paint over the canvas with my mouse by getting `Point`'s from the mouse using a `HashSet` and `Iterator`.

It also connects to another identical program via a `DatagramSocket` and sends the `Point`'s it generates to the other program which displays this on it's canvas.

To do this I use a `Runnable` thread that listens for incoming `Point`'s and adds them to the `HashSet`.

My problem is that i get `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` because I add `Point`'s to the `HashSet` from the connected program via the thread while painting.

I don't see how to get around this exception since I want the canvas to update live.

---

solved this using a `CopyOnWriteArraySet` with which I could simply replace my `HashSet` :) thx for all your support!

Comment: In the loop create a new Set and afterwards addAll the set to the original Set. Still concurrency issues arise during adding, so you have to guard that as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use [ConcurrentSkipListSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html) instead of **HashSet**. This Set implementation is **ordered** and **thread safe**.

As [MikeFHay mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59580053/adding-elements-to-a-hashset-while-iterating/59580282#comment105326972_59580282), you can also use another **thread safe** Set implementation - **ConcurrentHashMap.KeySetView**. It can be instantiated by using [ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#newKeySet--) method. This Set is **faster** then **ConcurrentSkipListSet** and is **not ordered**.

Comment: or `ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()`, which also supports concurrent modification, and is generally faster than ConcurrentSkipListSet.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the situation by locking the set. Use 'synchronized' block in both threads and lock the set before accessing them so no two threads modify the set at the same time.

[This might help](https://www.journaldev.com/378/java-util-concurrentmodificationexception)

Comment: Dope, but wouldn't this cause the cause each program to wait for updating the canvas with the points from the connected program until it finishes reading user input?

Comment: This drawback is mentioned in the link too. Locking an object will halt the update and retrieval at the same. But, if the threads aren't locking the object for a while, this method can be used to avoid the ConcurrentModificationException. Make sure you release the lock if the object is not being modified. Avoid locking the object for a while.